# Changing object that is retrieved by reference

Tags: java, jsp

I am working with JSP/Java and I got a question about the following code:

```
HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)pageContext.getSession();
SessionData sessionData = (SessionData)httpSession.getAttribute("data");
sessionData.setAccountId(account.getAccountId());
sessionData.setUsername(account.getUsername());
sessionData.setLoggedIn(true);
```

Do I need to call `httpSession.setAttribute("data", sessionData);` or not, and **should** I (still) do it or not?

As far as I understand objects are passed around by reference, but I don't know the details and I rather do it right in the first try.

Regards.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. `sessionData` is a reference.

Comment: You don't need it, but this is quite dangerous if you are not careful about what you are doing...

Comment: @fge Do you mean that he should be concerned about concurrency?

Comment: @crush no, one JSP "workflow" is in one thread and therefore operations happen in order within that thread; I am more worried about the "magic" happening with such statements.

Comment: Don't use JSP scriplets in your JSP pages. You should start using `JSTL`.

Comment: @RohitJain I've nowhere said that this is a JSP scriptlet. Infact it isn't, it is in a Java class being called via a taghandler, which ultimately comes from the JSP file.

Comment: @skiwi. Ok. It was not clear, b'coz you are having JSP page, and you used `pageContext` so I thought.

Comment: @RohitJain No problem. Maybe I'm not doing everything according to the perfect approach, but I am definately avoiding those nasty scriptlets :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to call httpSession.setAttribute("data", sessionData); or not,

No you don't need to do it. `sessionData` is a copy of the reference stored in the Session object. So whatever changes you make to the object using this reference, will be reflected for the reference stored in Session.

> As far as I understand objects are passed around by reference

No, nothing in Java are passed by reference. Everything is passed by value. In your case, it's the reference which is passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Java passes everything by value . Hence you don't need to do that. Object references are passed by value.